# Proving a sum identity

Tags: calculus

I'm sure there is an easy argument for the following identity, but I'm unable to figure it out. For $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>0$, why is it that
$$ 
q\ a^{1-1/q} = \sum_{i=0}^{q-1}(a^{1/q})^i(a^{1/q})^{q-1-i}.
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$(a^{1/q})^i (a^{1/q})^{q-1-i} = (a^{1/q})^{q-1}$$
Therefore, the expression inside the sum is not even dependent on i! And the sum is just this constant, times $q$ (the amount of times it's added).